# Noob question using legacy LWJGL with canvas

Tags: java, libgdx

Just installed libGDX & android studio yesterday.
My boss wants to use libGDX & javaFX (for UI) together in a project.

My assumptions:
It sounds like I can do that by using a canvas.
LWJGL3 does not support a canvas backend.
So i need to use the legacy LWJGL2

My question:
How in an existing project do I add legacy support and the libraries?

My current compile is failing with:
error: package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl does not exist import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglAWTCanvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are instructions [here](https://libgdx.com/news/2021/07/devlog-7-lwjgl3#how-can-i-migrate) for migrating from lwjgl2 to lwjgl3, so you can follow them in reverse.

Basically, change your module's dependency from `com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3` to `com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl` and change your launcher class to use LwjglApplication instead of Lwjgl3Application. The associated application configuration class works a bit differently, too. It uses  public fields instead of setter methods.